# Django application uWSGI have wrong datetime.today() result, shows started date

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I am trying to run an Django application behind NGINX and uWSGI but am having problems with `datetime.today()` returning the datetime from when the uWSGI server was started insted of today.
The configuration for the app is as follows:

```
    <uwsgi>
     <plugin>python</plugin>
       <socket>127.0.0.1:3030</socket>
       <chdir>/opt/ETS/bin</chdir>
       <pythonpath>..</pythonpath>
       <module>instance</module>
     </uwsgi>
```

The settings for the uWSGI is the defaults with no changes.

How can i get the datetime to work again?

Clarification:
the call is made in this function on access to a url

```
def create_file_header(name, ext):
    return {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=%s-%s.%s' % (name, datetime.date.today(), ext) }
```

the call is from a urlpatten:

```
(r'^loading_details/basic2/$', ExpandedResource(ReadLoadingDetailHandler, authentication=authentication, 
                                               headers=create_file_header('loading-details', 'csv')), 
 FORMAT_CSV, "api_loading_details_basic_auth"),
```

It worked when hosted on same server using Apache WSGI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you store `datetime.date.today()` in a module global, it will only be executed *once*, at server startup. This is not a server problem, but a problem with your code.

If you need a result to show *todays date*, you need to call the `datetime.date.today()` callable when you need todays date, not at startup.

Even if you were to call `today()` in a function, if that function itself is only called at module load time, it still is executed only once.

The URL patterns are generated only *once*. The `headers` keyword argument is not executed each time that URL is accessed, but only at module load time. You'll need to move creating tha header to the view itself.

Comment: I am not calling it on startup but from within an function

Comment: @tcarlander: And what calls that function? Is the *result* of that function stored at module load time?

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. I still do not see why it worked on Apache WSGI and not on uWSGI, I suppose that they run differently.

Comment: check the https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html page. It explains the fork() usage (and how you can change it)

Comment: @tcarlander: Apache probably started a *new* process for every URL you tested.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure is not the wrong timezone instead of uWSGI startup time ? uWSGI does not touch python internals (unless expressely requested in some area).

Comment: Yes I am sure, the date stays the same until I restart the uWSGI server.